# Underscore uniq not working in Parse

Tags: javascript, parse-platform, underscore.js

I've got a simple array `cars` of Parse models of class `Cars`

When I do

```
var uniqCars = _.uniq(cars);
```

it doesn't work. `uniqCars` is exact same as `cars`. The length of `cars` is 5 and length of `uniqCars` is 5 (when it should be 2).

However, when I do:

```
var uniqCars = _.uniq(cars,
    function (c) {
        return c.id;
    });
```

It works. My question is, why doesn't it work with the former and works with the latter? Why do I have to be so verbose? Is this an issue with Parse or underscore?

Comment: `_.uniq(cars, "id")` if you want a less verbose version

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why doesn't it work with the former

because, if you don't pass the comparator function, it by default uses `===` operator to compare the objects. Quoting the [`_.uniq`](http://underscorejs.org/#uniq) documentation,

> Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, **using === to test object equality**. ...  **If you want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an iteratee function**

When you use `===` ([Strict Equality operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Using_the_Equality_Operators)), no two objects will be the same unless they are one and the same object or same sequence of characters forming a string. For example,

```
console.assert(({} === {}) === false);
var obj = {};
console.assert(obj === obj);
console.assert("ab" === "a" + "b")
console.assert("ab" === 'a' + "b")
```

So, it is not specific to Parse but it is the expected behaviour in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

The comparisons are made using strict equality. Unless there are multiple references to the same object in the array, they are not going to be strictly equal.

> Produces a duplicate-free version of the array, using === to test object equality. In particular only the first occurence of each value is kept. If you know in advance that the array is sorted, passing true for isSorted will run a much faster algorithm. If you want to compute unique items based on a transformation, pass an iteratee function.